# Considering the negative energy density in the Casimir effect and general relativity worm holes, are these experiments feasible?

Tags: elementary-particles, wormholes, casimir-effect

The question came after I answered the question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/614356/is-this-solution-for-interstellar-travel-viable/614391?noredirect=1#comment1383129_614391), and  reading the [link provided](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0105070) where negative mass is needed to create wormholes,

> Microlensing by natural wormholes: theory and simulations

> We provide an in depth study of the theoretical peculiarities that arise in effective negative mass lensing

(Negative mass and the exotic particles that might represent it is another story)

The [negative mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_mass) article of wikipedia,

> Currently, the closest known real representative of such exotic matter is a region of negative pressure density produced by the Casimir effect.

AFAIK wormholes  are shortcuts

> [A wormhole can be visualized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole) as a tunnel with two ends at separate points in spacetime (i.e., different locations, different points in time, or both). "

This gave me the idea for  experiments with a particle beam that would show if the negative energy density mathematically seen in the Casimir effect could lead to a wormhole.

The idea is simple:

A high momentum particle beam from an accelerator passing through the space of the parallel plates has a probability to interact with the virtual photons of the Casimir field between the plates, which is calculable. Counting the beam tracks going through without interacting would show a discrepancy with the calculations if the negative energy density acts as a worm hole and part of the beam ends elsewhere instead of going through. It is a difficult experiment because the path of the particle should be coming within a nanometer accuracy to be able to go between the two plates.

If the above is possible experimentally, but the errors in the calculations are too large,  two Casimir sets can be  used as in this picture,

[image: casimir]

The detectors should be around the Casimir sets , in order to detect interactions between the plates and record their frequency. The barrier should be of absorbent material able to absorb any beam particle that hits it.

Comparing data without the  impenetrable barrier  , and then with the barrier in place would be proof of a wormhole existing if the second setup had a distribution of hits above the background  with no beam.

Of course the relative location of the Casimir setups could be different in the extra dimension, so no signal would not mean no wormhole.

NASA has advanced a lot in Casimir effect technology, see [here](https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=48852.0) , and maybe they could evaluate  the feasibility of such an experiment.

Comment: I cannot see how the mere presence of -ve energy would create a wormhole, which is a topological change; "exotic" matter is what you need to hold one open if one has a way of creating one (or grabbing it out of the "froth" - iff there is such a thing). Can you suggest any plausible mechanism by which it could create a wormhole... and in particular, where the "other end" would be located? Other comment: "Give the effect of FTL" - yes; "shortcuts through another dimension" - no, I think you are thinking of *embeddings* so Casimir setups always in the "same dimension".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole for various wormhole quesses, "A wormhole can be visualized as a tunnel with two ends at separate points in spacetime (i.e., different locations, different points in time, or both). " . "According to current theories on the nature of wormholes, construction of a traversable wormhole would require the existence of a substance with negative energy" . as negative energy mathematically appears in the Casimir effect I just propose a way to check if negative energy exists in this form.

Comment: "if the negative energy density acts as a worm hole"... you are assuming more than is justified on any theory I am aware of, thus even if -ve energy exists the predicted outcome is unlikely... personally I'd say a positive result would be of zero measure :) Just because keeping a wormhole open might need -ve energy, it does not follow that -ve energy creates a wormhole.

Comment: Sure, but if the experiment can be done and particles do disappear it will be an interesting experimental effect in any case, that would need new thinking or new physics.